# Cumulative link model: Test a coefficient against a value other than 0

Tags: r, ordinal-data, likelihood-ratio

I want to evaluate whether a coefficient from a CLM model is different from a value other than 0.  I'd like $p$-values, so computing confidence intervals doesn't get me want I want. I'm using `clm` from the `ordinal` package in R.

One option I've thought of is to use the standard errors returned by `clm` in a Wald test; so for coefficient $b$, test value $b'$, and standard error $SE$, compute

$$z=(b-b')/SE$$

and use $z$ to obtain the relevant $p$-value. However, I also know that $p$-values obtained from Wald tests are not always accurate in CLM models.

It also seems to me that I could evaluate the profile likelihood when coefficient $b$ is fixed at $b'$, then compare the profile likelihood to the likelihood of the model where $b$ is allowed to vary using a likelihood ratio test. While this sounds reasonable in theory, I'm not sure how to do it in practice. The `ordinal` package provides the function `profile`, but I don't know whether it's possible to use this function to compute the profile at a particular value of $b$.

If it's helpful, here's some `R` code to illustrate the issue.

```
library(ordinal)
set.seed(4345)
d <- data.frame(y=ordered(sample(1:7, size=200, replace=TRUE)),
                x1=rnorm(200), 
                x2=rnorm(200))
m <- clm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=d)

logLik(m)       #Log likelihood for this model
p <- profile(m) #Computes likelihood profiles for x1 and x2
                #Can I use this to compute a p-value testing x1=.5?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a likelihood ratio test. Basically it comes down to a model comparison. You explicitly fit the small/null model, then also fit the large/unconstrained model, then take -2 times the difference in model log-likelihoods as the test statistic (the likelihood ratio). Under the null hypothesis this has a chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom parameter equal to the difference in number of unconstrained coefficients (1 in this case).

Most software packages have nice utilities for doing this sort of thing. You mentioned that you're using `clm` in R. In R the process should look something like this (untested!), for an example where we test whether the `z` coefficient differs from 2:

```
model_C <- clm(y ~ x + offset(2*z))
model_A <- clm(y ~ x + z)
anova(model_C, model_A)
```